# How to set UICollectionView Item Size, if the CollectionView is inside a UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

I have a UICollectionView at the end of a UIScrollView added in the storyboard. (The scroll view's content height is fixed via autolayout), also I have returned the collection view's cell size through `sizeForItemAtindexPath`, but the cell size is different from what is provided and each cell have different sizes. The other behaviours like scrolling is working fine. How to set the cell size properly when the UICollectionView is inside UIScrollView?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: @Frankenstein there is no much code, I've added everything in storyboard and `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 200, height: 100)
    } ` by code.

Comment: @Frankenstein
Setting the collection view's estimated cell size to `None` did the trick for me, the cell size is as expected. Any inputs on this?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the UICollectionView's estimated cell size to None in the Identity inspector worked for me.
[Check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYyj8.png)